# woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments не обновляет контент

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

Всё происходит на странице корзины:

```
<span class="total-count-products">Товаров в корзине: <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
```

При загрузке всё хорошо. После обновления количества товаров меняется цена, общая цена. Но количество не могу обновить, использую такой хук:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {
    $fragments['span.total-count-products'] = ' <span class="total-count-products">Товаров в корзине: '. WC()
            ->cart->get_cart_contents_count(). '</span>';

    return $fragments;
}
```

Но ничего не происходит. Так же пробовал после завершения аякс запроса использовать такую функцию:

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragment_refresh' );
```

Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Выглядит правильно, на сайте есть селектор span.total-count-products? Не является ли он частью другого фрагмента? В консоли есть ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

У меня этот хук работает:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {
    $fragments['span.total-count-products'] = ' <span class="total-count-products">Товаров в корзине: '. WC()
            ->cart->get_cart_contents_count(). '</span>';
        return $fragments;
}
```

Какие-то ошибки есть в консоли?

Comment: Спасибо, но так давно было, что я уже не помню, в каком проекте была данная задача